# "typeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined."

Tags: javascript, mysql, promise, discord.js, userid

Here is my code for the `>top10` command of my discord bot:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async(bot, message, args, con) => {

  const top10query = `SELECT user, points, lstmsg FROM scores WHERE guild = '${message.guild.id}' ORDER BY cast(points as SIGNED) ASC LIMIT 10`
  //const top10 = con.query(top10query)

  const query = querytxt => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      con.query(querytxt, (err, results, fields) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        resolve([results, fields]);
      });
    });
  };
  const [results, fields] = await query(top10query);

  const map1 = results.map(results => `User: ${(bot.fetchUser(results.user)).username} Messages: ${results.points} Last message: ${results.lstmsg}`);
  message.channel.send(map1)
}
module.exports.help = {
  name: "top10",
  usage: "``prefix`` top10",
  description: "top 10 points",
}
```

The data for "user" is stored as the user ID. I get 'undefined' when I use the >top10 command.

[image: undefined user]

Any ideas?

---

**EDIT:**
I've tried replacing

```js
const map1 = results.map(results => `User: ${(bot.fetchUser(results.user)).username} Messages: ${results.points} Last message: ${results.lstmsg}`);
      message.channel.send(map1)
```

With

```js
const map1 = results.map(results => `User: ${(bot.users.get(results.user.id)).username} Messages: ${results.points} Last message: ${results.lstmsg}`);
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
(node:21128) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
```

Comment: I'm assuming `bot.fetchUser(results.user)).username` this is the line throwing the error. Have you done any logging above it, such as logging out `results.user` and then `bot.fetchUser(results.user)` to make sure you're getting back what you expect?

Comment: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined` when I log `console.log(bot.fetchUser(results.user))`

Comment: `bot.fetchUser(results.user)` is async

Comment: First of all you can just use .fetchUser with a bot account (written in the djs docs). Try to log if you even get an user with bot.users.get(...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```js
User: ${(bot.fetchUser(results.user)).username
```

with:

```js
User: ${bot.users.get(results.user).username
```

Comment: I think it would be preffered to keep fetchUser()  as its a leaderboard, where users might not be in bot.users

Comment: Its not a function, its a class / object

Answer (score 0):

You want to do

```
const map1 = await results.map(async result => {
        const user = await client.fetchUser(result);
        return `User: ${user.username} Messages: ${result.points} Last message: ${result.lstmsg}`; 
});
```